# Is it possible to shorten the code even further?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am a lover of beautiful and short code, and here a problem arises ... short of course, but not beautiful. Can this code be made more beautiful?

```
app.post('/xsolla/', (req, res) => new Xsolla(req, res));
```

tried this option but it didn't work

```
app.post('/xsolla/', new Xsolla);
```

Comment: A utility function (or a static `Xsolla` factory function) that takes the request/response and builds the `Xsolla`. I question the ROI, though.

Comment: What is beautiful to you may not be beautiful to other developers who have to work with your code. (See also: practical, maintainable. readable)

Comment: @Andy there are comments for such cases

Comment: What module on NPM are you getting `Xsolla` from?  I wanted to look at how that works to see if you can avoid creating a new object for every new request.

Comment: FYI, it's clear why the 2nd option doesn't work.  That constructs your object with no arguments sent to the constructor and then passes that object to Express as the request handler.  That is far, far different than what your first option does and you have to pass a function to Express as a request handler, not an object.

Comment: @jfriend00 own sdk. I know that this cannot be done in the second way, I just gave an example of how I would like to see it

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use rest parameters instead of repeating them:

```
app.post('/xsolla/', (...args) => new Xsolla(...args));
```

But keep in mind that *readable* code is more important than *short* code.

[`Reflect.construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct) (in combination with `.bind`) would *almost* do the trick for removing the need to list arguments altogether, but unfortunately it takes the arguments to be passed to the constructor as an array in the second argument, rather than as separate items in the argument list.

Comment: In my opinion this is less clear than the code in the question, since in express, the callbacks passed to functions like `app.post()` can have different arities, and this makes it less obvious which arity is expected to be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you were doing this in multiple places and just wanted to avoid repeated code, you could make yourself a reusable request handler:

```
function xHandler(req, res) {
    new Xsolla(req, res);
}

app.post('/xsolla/', xHandler);
```